# Google Chrome(Version 79.0.3945.117) crashes again and again while debugging the application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

***"Dev Tool was disconnected from the page."***

I am confused, is this issue with my application only or this version(79.0.3945.117) of Chrome introduced this issue.

See the screenshot of what it says when I try to debug my application.

[image]

Comment: Same with me - infuriating, if I want to check a property I need to log it to console